# How do I disable the USB Connected notification?

Tags: notifications, usb, usb-debugging

Every time I plug in my phone, I get a notification for USB connected. Is there any way to disable the notification, without disabling USB debugging?

- Phone: LG Optimus S
- Carrier: Sprint
- Android: 2.2, Rooted

Comment: Why is it a problem?  It's there so you can mount your phone storage (to copy files to/from the computer) if you so choose.

Comment: @Matthew Read Yes, but it makes a sound. I would prefer to be notified of only SMS and email. I also have Dual Mount SD, so I do not need to use the notification for mounting the SD card.

Comment: But it only makes a sound at the moment that you plug it in, it's pretty easy to tell that's not a new message notification?

Comment: @GAThrawn But if I restart my computer with the phone plugged in...

Comment: I still wish to be able to use this functionality but not have the popup because it distracts from using the UI (e.g. when the cable used occasionally disconnects, and USB is not currently in use anyway), besides it's in the notification bar anyway so I can access it.

Comment: I just want to charge my device...

Comment: A sound that you don't want to hear is just _annoying_. There should be an option to disable it.

Comment: On Android 13, just go to "Settings > Notification > App notifications > Android system" and disable "Important developer messages".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the sound is what you don't like, on some phones the sound can be turned off by disabling USB Debugging. `Settings` -> `Applications` -> `Development` -> `USB debugging`. However, on some other phones, this will not change the sound that gets played when you plug it in.

To actually remove the notification, as previously mentioned, you'll need a custom ROM to do that for you.

[Update]
Another option to disable the sound is to go into your Sounds settings and set the default notification ringtone to silent and then go to each and every one of your applications that you want to have ringtones in and individually set them up there. I don't recommend this option (sure would be a pain if you forgot to set a ringtone to work email and missed an important one saying "We need you here ASAP or you're fired!"), but it is an option nonetheless.

Comment: I tried the second option, but that did not work out very well for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of a Core system in android. It can not be disabled unless you have a ROM that allows you to disable it. I believe 6.x versions of CyanogenMod have/had the option to disable it.

I am not sure if your phone is supported, and I am not sure if that option is still there (since my device doesn't have "official" support currently)

Comment: Ah, well. Was worth a shot to ask.

Answer (score 1):

One option **without rooting** is to use a simple app like this one: [Mute](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=muter.muter).

The only thing this app does is toggles between a muted / not muted state when opened.

Note that this mutes *all* sounds, not just the *`USB connected in debug mode`* notification. So for disabling that annoying sound (for example, when debugging at night), this is perfect. Just don't forget to turn it off after the debugging session.